# Books like "Jeux de l'esprit et divertissements mathématiques"

Tags: recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation, big-list

I have enjoyed the second edition of the title's book (*Nouveaux jeux de l'esprit et divertissements mathématiques*) and now I have bought the first edition. To set some context, the book has some "games" (problems), some of them require a few skills (or none) on logic and math, and other ones need more time and more knowledge on mathematical concepts. I am interested in books like this, or other books with problems of logic, puzzles, etc (Obviously, related to mathematics, mathematical concepts and logic).

I'm not interested in books of sudoku, and puzzles like that (just because there are a lot of books with that content).

---

Thanks for your answers and have a nice day!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_mathematics#People A shame that [Raymond Smullyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan) is not in this list...

Comment: The dozens of books by Martin Gardner or about Martin Gardner like this excellent one : "Homage to a Pied Puzzler", Edited by Ed Pegg, Alan H. Schoen, Tom Rodgers, AK Peters, 208

Comment: An old classic book in Italian: "Matematica dilettevole e curiosa" (Amusing and curious Mathematics) by Italo Ghersi (https://www.amazon.it/Matematica-dilettevole-curiosa-Italo-Ghersi/dp/8820304694)